# EWS JAVA API get all meetings from attendee with organizer

Tags: java, calendar, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to get all meetings with all information from a user/email from our Exchange Server.

For that I'm using the [EWS JAVA API library](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api).

Now I'm stuck at that point, that I don't get all informations like the organizer and the members. I'm getting just the start and end time, the availability code and the subject. And yes the user has the correct rights to lookup for all other informations.

Here is the code which I found from the tutorials:

```
List<AttendeeInfo> attendees = new ArrayList<>();
attendees.add(new AttendeeInfo("user@bla.com"));

Date start = new Date();
Date end = new Date(start.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

// Call the availability service.
GetUserAvailabilityResults results = exchange.getUserAvailability(attendees, new TimeWindow(start, end), AvailabilityData.FreeBusy);

// Output attendee availability information.
int attendeeIndex = 0;

for (AttendeeAvailability attendeeAvailability : results.getAttendeesAvailability()) {
    System.out.println("Availability for " + attendees.get(attendeeIndex));
    if (attendeeAvailability.getErrorCode() == ServiceError.NoError) {
        for (CalendarEvent calendarEvent : attendeeAvailability.getCalendarEvents()) {
            System.out.println("Calendar event");
            System.out.println("  Start time: " + calendarEvent.getStartTime().toString());
            System.out.println("  End time: " + calendarEvent.getEndTime().toString());

            if (calendarEvent.getDetails() != null) {
                System.out.println("  Subject: " + calendarEvent.getDetails().getSubject());
            }
        }
    }

    attendeeIndex++;
}
```

Is there maybe another way to get all informations which I need?
I couldn't find anything what comes close to that what I already have.

Answer (score 1):

Well ... through a typo in google I found a solution ...

```
CalendarView cView = new CalendarView(start, end);
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox("user@bla.com"));
FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = exchange.findAppointments(folderId, cView);
ArrayList<Appointment> calItem = findResults.getItems();
```

`calItem` has all informations about all appointments from the user